# В Firefox закладка отладчик совершенно пустая

Tags: firefox

В Firefox закладка "отладчик" в инструментах разработки вдруг стала совершенно пустой - не отображается ни список js-файлов, ни их содержимое, ни кнопки пауза-пуск и другие на этой закладке. Остальные закладки инструментов разработки в порядке. Перезапускал браузер без дополнений - не помогло. Переустанавливать не хочется, версия самая последняя. JavaScript на странице работает, консоль тоже, инструмент "простой редактор JavaScript" работает нормально. Что это может быть?

Comment: а в других браузерах?

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос закрыт. Недели две промучался с отладкой в непривычном хроме, и вот, стоило написать вопрос, как Firefox вдруг обновился (какая-то кардинально новая версия: Quantum 57) и баг исчез.